# session id does not propagate through url

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

i am a php newbie. I know it's create a security hole but it is only for testing and learning reason. I found that session.use_trans_id=true and session.use_cookies=false settings compel the browser to transfer session id through url. But it is not happening. I am using two php file. For better under standing i am copying the codes here
Im test8.php file-

```
ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
//ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",0);
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
session_start();
echo ini_get("session.use_trans_sid");
echo ini_get("session.use_cookies");
$_SESSION['name']="sovon";
?>
<form action="test9.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart-formn/data" >
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<a href="test9.php">click</a>
```

In test9.php file-

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "</br>";
echo ini_get("session.use_trans_sid");
echo  "</br>";
echo ini_get("session.use_cookies");
echo  "</br>";
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

whether i submit the form or click on the link session id is not transferring by url. At test9.php file the session.use_trans_id becomes false again. But the value of the variable is not showing. I tried it by stopping cookie in browser. But still not working.

Am i understanding wrong? What is the wrong?
please help me ?
waiting for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful of messing with $_SESSION, for example don't initialise it with an array as in: $_SESSION = array(). It gets confused on windows anyway. I had to reboot the pc to get sessions working properly again. whatever...

I provide your scripts, with some minor errors removed, below.

I have added 'var_dumps' of all the relevant areas that PHP maintains for storing session keys.

Please note:

The $_SESSION['name'] is always preserved.

1) The session id is returned in the '$_GET' array if you click on the link.

2) The session id is returned in '$_POST' when you click on the form.

p.s. no cookies were used in the making of this answer.

Tested Code: PHP 5.3.18 on windows xp.

Q23172926_index

```
<?php // Q23172926_index

ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
//ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",0);
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
session_start();
echo ini_get("session.use_trans_sid");
echo ini_get("session.use_cookies");
$_SESSION['name']="sovon";
?>
<form action="Q23172926_test9.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart-form/data" >
<input type="text" name="name" value="who are you?"/>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go For It!"/>
</form>
<a href="Q23172926_test9.php">click</a>
<?php
var_dump(__FILE__ . ' after HTML output',
        '$_GET ==}', $_GET, '{== $_GET',
        '$_SESSION ==}', empty($_SESSION) ? 'no session yet' : $_SESSION, '{== $_SESSION',
        '$_COOKIE ==}',empty($_COOKIES) ? 'no cookies' : $_COOKIES, '{== $_COOKIES',
        '$_POST ==}', $_POST, '{== $_POST' );
```

Q23172926_test9

```
<?php // Q23172926_test9
var_dump(__FILE__ . '  before session_start() -- check $_GET / $_POST for session_id
        '$_SESSION ==}', empty($_SESSION) ? 'no session yet' : $_SESSION, '{== $_SESSION',
        '$_COOKIE ==}',empty($_COOKIES) ? 'no cookies' : $_COOKIES, '{== $_COOKIES',
         '$_POST ==}', $_POST, '{== $_POST' );

session_start();

var_dump(__FILE__ . ' After session start',
        '$_SESSION ==}', empty($_SESSION) ? 'no session yet' : $_SESSION, '{== $_SESSION'
        );

echo session_id();
echo "</br>";
echo ini_get("session.use_trans_sid");
echo  "</br>";
echo ini_get("session.use_cookies");
echo  "</br>";
echo 'Name should be here ==}', $_SESSION['name'] ,' {== Name should be here';
```